Disable web links in pdf using python
I'm looking to create a Python script to disable web links in a PDF.
I've attempted to remove annotations using PyPDF2, but the output remains unchanged. I've tried several approaches, but none have successfully removed the hyperlinks.
My goal is to make the web links appear as regular text, without changing the actual link. The link should remain the same, but function as plain text instead of a clickable hyperlink.
Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Indeed, as the answer referenced by @KJ illustrates, some viewers (in particular Adobe Acrobat) look for text that looks like an URL and makes it clickable. Unless you have control over the viewer in question, therefore, you have to disfigure the URLs in the PDF.

I found this bit of code that might help you.  It searches your entire document and removes any hyperlinks within it.
import aspose.pdf as pdf
from io import BytesIO

# Load input PDF document
pdfDoc = pdf.Document("PDFWithHyperLinks.pdf")
for p in pdfDoc.pages:
    for annot in p.annotations:
        if annot.annotation_type == pdf.annotations.AnnotationType.LINK:
            p.annotations.delete(annot)

# Save the output PDF after deleting hyperlinks
pdfDoc.save("PdfWithoutHyperlinks.pdf")

print("Hyperlinks removed successfully")

Credit to Aspose Knowledge Base

The shortest solution I can think of (assuming all annotations are links):
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter

pdf = PdfReader('in.pdf')
for page in pdf.pages:
    page.Annots = None
PdfWriter('out.pdf', trailer=pdf).write()

More info: pdfrw
